# Change default Activity dynamically

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to be able to change which `Activity` is run when the user runs the application.

I know how to do this in the application's manifest file, but I would like to do it programmatically after install. The reason being, I want the user to be able to choose which screen loads when he opens the application.

How can I do this? The only way I know of seems very clunky: have an essentially empty Activity which has the MAIN intent-filter - which then reads the user's settings and transfers the user to the desired Activity. This creates a lot of mess, like the back-stack needs to be considered, and the overheads of loading one activity straight after another seems wasteful of time and resources.

Comment: it is the only way. Remeber to finish the empty activity after you started the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change launcher activity dynamically.

As you said it is possible by saving user preferences and start desired activity each time. I have tried it and it is fast enough to not show itself. Don't remember to call finish on main activity. it will solve back stack problem.

Also you can use different fragments for different activities and decide which one should be added to main activity. It may be faster. However as I said it is fast enough to start a new activity and hide main activity because it is done in onCreate method. Don't worry about that.